ZFS userdata has disappeared without any errors after the reboot
After the reboot, part of the data on tank/rpool has disappeared. There are no tank/rpool/USERDATA/root_xxxx11 and tank/rpool/USERDATA/user_xxxx11. There are no error messages in the zpool status or scrub. The smartctl status has "passed" for all disks.
Before the reboot, I experimented with incremental backups using snapshot send.
I have backups, but not all of the data is included in the backups.
It is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
# zpool list
no pools available

# zpool import -lR /mnt tank
Enter passphrase for 'tank/rpool':
1 / 1 keys successfully loaded

# zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:19:03 with 0 errors on Mon Oct  7 07:33:16 2024
remove: Removal of vdev 1 copied 7.19G in 0h1m, completed on Wed Apr 10 18:05:33 2024
    122K memory used for removed device mappings
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
      66969040-8f95-6f4d-aca3-dfe34ff2d1f7  ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdb1                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      sdc3                                  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

# ls /mnt/home/user/
mnt  tmp

Where is my files?!
# zfs mount -a

# ls /mnt/home/user/
mnt  tmp

# zfs list | grep USERDATA
tank/rpool/USERDATA                                                                               168K   374G      168K  /mnt

# zfs list -t snapshot | grep USERDATA
tank/rpool/USERDATA@rpool.initial_20240908                                                                                     0B      -      168K  -
tank/rpool/USERDATA@rpool.incremental_20241006                                                                                 0B      -      168K  -

# zpool history tank|tail
2024-10-06.07:05:50 zpool import -N tank
2024-10-06.07:06:12 zfs load-key tank/rpool
2024-10-06.06:16:00 zfs snapshot -r tank/rpool@rpool.incremental_20241006
2024-10-06.06:59:35 zfs send --raw -Rvi tank/rpool@rpool.initial_20240908 tank/rpool@rpool.incremental_20241006
2024-10-07.08:34:09 zpool export tank
2024-10-07.08:40:47 zpool import -lR /mnt tank

# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank   492G   106G   386G        -         -    19%    21%  1.00x    ONLINE  /mnt

# df -h
--cut--
tank/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_xxxx                          428G   58G  371G  14% /mnt
--cut--

# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank   492G   106G   386G        -         -    19%    21%  1.00x    ONLINE  /mnt

# df -h
--cut--
tank/rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_xxxx                          428G   58G  371G  14% /mnt
--cut--

About 50GB of data in tank/rpool/USERDATA/user_xxxx11 has disappeared.
Any help would be appreciated.

Be aware that if your details are correct; your details show you've not been applying all security fixes & other upgrades for awhile. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/ will show the ISO release date of 22.04.5, but installed systems upgraded before that date to 22.04.5.

If you have the zsys package installed it might destroy (totally) filesystems under USERDATA. It's happened to me. It's one of the reasons I ensure zsys is never installed on any system I manage. See https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+userdata+destroyed for issues related to this. I strongly recommend you uninstall zsys.
